# problem with assigning data correctly to formular with ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, ngmodel, two-way-binding

I'm trying to assign the retrieved data to a form. The data is correctly retrieved, but when I attempt to pass each value of the data to its corresponding input or select, it doesn't place them correctly. Interestingly, when I display each value before the input, the value appears correct.
here is my class object :

```
export class ConfigGeneral {
    idConfigGeneral?: number;
    libelleInterneCabinet?: string;
    devise?: string;
}
```

this is the typescript component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ConfigGeneral } from 'src/app/models/cabinet/configCabinet/ConfigGeneral';
import {ConfigGeneralService} from '../../../Services/cabinet/configuration/config-general.service';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-parametre-general',
  templateUrl: './parametre-general.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parametre-general.component.scss']
})
export class ParametreGeneralComponent implements OnInit {
  configGeneral : ConfigGeneral 

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal,
    private configGeneralService:ConfigGeneralService) { 
      this.configGeneral  = new ConfigGeneral()
    }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.getConfigurationGeneral()
  }

getConfigurationGeneral(){
    this.configGeneralService.getConfigGeneralOfCabinet().pipe
      (tap((data)=>{
        if (data != null){
          console.log(data)
          this.configGeneral=data;  
          console.log(this.configGeneral)
        }
        })
      ).subscribe();
  }
}
```

and here is the form of the html component (I will focus on only two values "libelleInterneCabinet" and "devise" to make it clear and readable)

```
                  <form >
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label" for="libelleInterne">Libelle interne du cabinet</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                          {{configGeneral.libelleInterneCabinet}}
                          <input class="form-control" id="libelleInterne" type="text" [(ngModel)]="configGeneral.libelleInterneCabinet">
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label" for="devise">Devise</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                          {{configGeneral.devise}}
                                <select class="form-select" id="devise" [(ngModel)]="this.configGeneral.devise">
                                    <option value="Euro">Euro</option>
                                </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
```

and here's the result of the two console.logs in `getConfigurationGeneral()` methode :

```
devise: "Euro"
libelleInterneCabinet: "cabinet"
```

this is how it is displayed in the figure

[screen shot of the interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDik9.png)

actually, I haven't tried anything yet because I can't identify the problem in my code. I hope I can find an answer. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I suggest you share only the [minimum](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code that shows the issue (maybe only a single field that is displayed incorrectly).  As you have it, there is a lot of code for others to dig through and try to understand.

Comment: Okay, sorry for that. I will minimize it.

Comment: I have minimized the code. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pasted your code into [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-76282241-original?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fmain.html&devtoolsHeight=50) and saw the following error:

> Error: NG01352: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
> control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

Do you see this error on your end?

The problem is resolved by simply using the `name` attribute instead of the `id` attribute:

```html
<input type="text" name="libelleInterne" [(ngModel)]="configGeneral.libelleInterneCabinet" />
```

Here's the updated [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-76282241-solution?file=src%2Fmain.html&devtoolsHeight=50)

Comment: I don't have any error on my end that mentions NG01352 and Thank you so much for your assistance. It has solved the problem.